# Custom static cell in tableView with others prototype cells

Tags: swift, uitableview, custom-cell

By these lines I created a table view with the first cell static and the other prototypes

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return 2
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    switch section
    {
    case 0 : return 1
    case 1 : return elenco.cori.count
    default : fatalError("No rows!")
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell : UITableViewCell!
    switch (indexPath.section)
    {
    case 0 :
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("container", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Squadra"

    case 1 :
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        let coro = elenco.cori[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = coro.marker
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    default : fatalError("No cells!")
    }
        return cell
}
```

and now I'd like to modify the first cell height (not 44 as the other, but 120); i tried in the inspector, but running the project didn't work. Is there other methods to increase the static cell height programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `tableView(_:heightForRowAtIndexPath:)`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
    switch indexPath.section {
        case 0: return 120
        case 1: return 44
        default: fatalError("...")
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, this is my first app; probably lots of my questions may look stupid...
curious, why I can not fix cell height in the size inspector?
Thanks a lot!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: It gets reset at runtime by the delegate I'd say. Just remember to use documentation and look for already answered questions in here ;)